# Trying to reduce memory impact in a for loop Swift (4)

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, memory-management

I have a pdf document (approx 200 pages). I run a for loop to iterate all the pages in turn and scrape it for some strings and stores in an Array.

This however results in a crash

> Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue.

Im trying to reduce the size of the memory by removing elements from the array but despite the array being shortened the data size remains the same how is this?

```
let document = PDFDocument(url: documentURL)
document?.delegate = self

let numberOfPages = CGFloat((document?.pageCount)!)

var pageText : String?

for page in 0...Int(numberOfPages) {

    if document?.page(at: page)?.string != nil {
        pageText = document?.page(at: page)?.string

        var parameters: [String]?
        parameters = pageText?.components(separatedBy: "Train From")

        pageText = nil //pageText now stored in parameters variable so set to nil

        if parameters!.count > 1 && parameters!.count < 3 { 
            print(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: parameters!), ">", parameters!.count)
            parameters!.removeLast() // we only need first item
            print(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: parameters!), ">>", parameters!.count)
        }
    }
}
```

the print out is

> 8 > 2
>
> 8 >> 1

so the array is removing an element yet its size remains 8?
How, why?

I need to free up memory in my for loop.

Comment: A Swift `Array` is a struct with a fixed size (which happens to be 8), and hidden pointers to the element storage.

Comment: It *might* help to execute the loop body in an `autoreleasepool`.

Comment: i still get "Terminated due to memory issue." if I run in an autoreleasepool{}. does swift keep a reference to all objects until the loop completes.If so this could explain the memory problem but how to solve if some of the objects are let so cannot be set to nil.

Comment: did you try declaring the parameters array outside the loop?

Comment: yeah same "Terminated due to memory issue."

Comment: do you need pagetext? it's copying that string.

Comment: You could try to Profile in Instruments to see what's eating all the memory.

Answer (score 1):

When you use MemoryLayout.size you get the size of memory of that type. But a struct with a fixed size, so you see the size of that cell.

You should duplicate in the count of the cells:

```
print(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: parameters!) * parameters!.count, ">", parameters!.count)
parameters!.removeLast() // we only need first item
print(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: parameters!) * parameters!.count, ">>", parameters!.count)
```

Comment: An `Array`is not just the pointer to the first cell. It isn't a pointer at all. Swift is not C.